# Adding conference header to bottom of poster

Tags: posters

[This is](https://www.overleaf.com/read/fmrcmmxpczsc) the current version of my undergrad conference poster. It must have a header at its bottom, such as in the sample .ppt:

[image]

What's the best way of adding that header to my poster?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please do not link to external information as this may be lost. You can add both your source code and an image result in your question

Comment: Thanks for the greetings. Since the question is about formatting, I can't think of how to build a minimal working example here. The overleaf link has the code I'm using, but if I pasted it here it'd be way too long. How should I proceed?

Comment: You should provide a light example (hence minimal) sufficient to reproduce you problem but without unnecessary piece of code

Comment: You could replace the `\color{imeRed}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.2cm}}` (which is wrong syntax, `\color{...}` is a switch and only takes one argument) with an image of the footline.

Comment: Off-topic: never use `.jpg` for graphs, the quality is horrible. Please also reconsider the choice of font. I would find it difficult to read on a poster.

Comment: Why are you loading the `geometry` package multiple times?

Comment: Thanks for the unrelated feedback. I'm trying to replay the graphs in .ps and I had forgotten to delete one of the geometry loads. What do you mean by "\color is a switch"?

Comment: @big-lion That instead of writing `\color{red}{text}` it should be `{ \color{red} text }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE.

You can add the image using the `fancyhdr` package as a page footer. This answer places it as a footer in relation to the page coordinate, `current page.south`. This is done by creating a node into which you insert your image `sic`. The anchor of the image is its `south` coordinate. The result is that the south coordinate of the page is connected to the south coordinate of the image. The width of the image is equal to `\pagewidth`, which was passed to `geometry` and set in the class options for `a0poster` (declaring it in `geometry` is probably redundant).

You also need to load the `graphicx` package to use `\includegraphics` to add the image. The poster body is filled with text from the `lipsum` package.

Help will always come much faster when you supply a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that people can provide input to. Just setup the example and explain what you are having trouble with. Happy TeXing.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=60cm,paperheight=90cm,margin=4cm}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % output de ácentos
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % input de àcentos
\usepackage{lipsum}      % <--- Added for blind text
\usepackage{graphicx}    % <--- Added to insert footer image
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    %<--- Added to access page footer (and header if desired)
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}  % multi colunas
%--------------------------------------
% Add the footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
% a generic image would be example-image-plain
% the image "sic" was supplied by OP
\node (footer) at ([yshift=-0.2cm]current page.south) [anchor=south] {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=4cm]{sic}};
\end{tikzpicture}
    }
%------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
\begin{center}
{\color{blue} \Huge \textsc{Title}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\hrule

\setlength{\columnsep}{40pt}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-16]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]